# ggplot:boxplot:presentations

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following out :

```
t1      t2    res
103    19  28.66667
222    49  28.66667
140    36  28.66667
102    33  24.66667
88     37  24.66667
38     22  24.66667
34     19  36.00000
102    25  36.00000
506    25  36.00000
73     9   39.00000
55     17  39.00000
34    17   39.00000
20    22   38.33333
50    67   38.33333
30    19   38.33333
27    15   34.00000
40    21   34.00000
35    16   34.00000
34    17   37.00000
22    29   37.00000
12    30   37.00000
25    39   26.33333
20    53   26.33333
22    20   26.33333
```

I have plotted the boxplot of both of t1 and t2 in Y-axis and res in X-axis, after I reshape the data and melt them. My question is how to to choose the color inside each of results and is it possible to change the filling to grid or shadowing filling so if I print the graph in black and white I will be still able to differentiate between t1 and t2 boxplot. 
below is my code, it is auto generating different color but I want be able to choose!!:

```
ggplot(df_melted, aes(x = factor(res), y =value, fill=variable)) +
geom_boxplot(las=1,varwidth=T,border="black",col="red",medlwd=3,whiskcol="black",staplecol="blue",top=T)+
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 200))
```

Note: df_melted is the data after applying melt command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scale_fill_grey` and `theme_bw` could be what you're after.
Try this:

```
ggplot(df_melted, aes(x = factor(res), y =value, fill=variable)) +
   geom_boxplot()+
   scale_fill_grey(start = .5, end = .9) +
   theme_bw()
```